# What is importance of author listings when resumé/CV differs from actual publication?

Tags: cv, authorship

In examining published papers of employment applicants, I am noticing that authorship position shown on the resumé/CV (first, second, third authors, etc.) do not match those shown in the published papers. Is this significant? The field is cognitive neuroscience. My applicants are often shown as First Author on their CV, but not on the published papers. Is this significant in any way?

Comment: Is this industry or academia?  I think it makes a difference, although I expect disagreement.

Comment: In general, I think it is inappropriate to rearange author positions. But would make a difference between _middle_ authors (for N authors, this are the ones from position 2 to N-1) and _first_ and _last_ author because they imply a special role. So if someone claims to be the first author but isn't, it's kind of a misstatement for me, while claiming to be author 2 instead of author N-1 wouldn't bother me much.

Comment: That's imo sufficient reason to immediately trash the application. If it's a young student, write him a note explaining how inappropriate it is to take credit for other people's work.

Comment: In fields where "first author" means something, promoting oneself to first author on one's CV is dishonest. In fields like mine, where authors are almost always ordered alphabetically, putting one's own name first seems pointless but also harmless.

Answer (score 9):

In general, author position must be the same on a CV as it is in the official publication. Changing author position on the CV is generally deceptive. In particular, first authorship often conveys a greater role on a publication. So this may suggest the applicant is trying to indicate that they had a greater role in the publication than they did.

That said, it seems like a rather strange thing for an applicant to do. If someone is going for an academic job, it is common that the employer would have a look at a few publications. Thus, it would quickly become evident that CV and publication differ in author-order. And this would typically be perceived poorly by the employer.

A common and better strategy is to bold or star your own name in the CV (and perhaps the names of students you have supervised). This makes it easier for a reader of a CV to scan author position.

Comment: Strike "should", insert "must". It's definitively fraudulent, and if the journal has alphabetic ordering of author names, also insulting to the reader. Another thing is omitting a half-dozen other "middle" authors names.